# Do I need to have a separate installation of conda for each server with a different Centos version?

Tags: python, centos, conda

I would like to use my conda environment on different machines that all access the same file system. Currently, I have conda installed on this file system and I have created an environment on one of the machines which runs Centos 7. When I try to activate my environment on a machine running Centos 6 I receive an error (version `GLIBC_2.17' not found). Is it safe to create a new conda environment on this Centos 6 machine, or is it best to have a separate install of conda entirely to avoid these errors?

Comment: What Conda **base** do you use (e.g., Anaconda, Miniconda, or Miniforge variant)? Last I know, Conda Forge still [builds with the CentOS 6 sysroot](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/announcements.html#centos-7-docker-images-are-now-the-default), so as long as all your packages in the **base** environment are from Conda Forge, you should be able to use the same Conda (or, better, Mamba). Anaconda explicitly only supports CentOS 7+, so any packages from `defaults` channels will not be compatible.

Comment: Another option is a statically-built binary, like [Micromamba](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/micromamba.html). It implements most of the Conda functionality without having to run out of a **base** environment.